# How do I collect arguments from the command-line?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cygwin, command-line-interface

I am very new to shell scripting and using CLI all together. However, I want to create a simple program that can collect arguments from a user.

Optimally, I want my shell script to get a network name and instance name from the user, and assign the values to variables.

I know that $# can be used to gather arguments, but are there any other ways? I often notice when I make a command, there is, for example, something like this: $create --instance_name NAME . Can I gather an argument by using -- to specify the parameter? If so, here is an example of the command:

`$collect_variable.sh --network NETWORK_NAME --instance_name INSTANCE_ID`

Once again, thank you for any help. I am very new to stack overflow and unix all together, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50879690/7552

Comment: or http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php

Answer (score 0):

You can using a variable to assign to for example:

```
 while getopts "x:y:z:" res
  do
   case "$res" in
     x ) paramX="$OPTARG" ;;
     y ) paramY="$OPTARG" ;;
     z ) paramX="$OPTARG" ;;
     ? ) echo "not a valid value"
   esac
  done
```

Check the rest of the links that other StackO users sent, they provide great examples!
Hope that can help you solve your issue.
Peace!

Comment: I will give this a try, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of gathering arguments. You can name their position, e.g. `$1` is the first argument and `$14` is the fourteenth.

You can refer to the argument list like `$@` (this preserves spacing) or like `$*` (this collapses spacing):

```sh
test_args() {
  echo '# as "$@"'
  for argument in "$@"; do
    echo "$argument"
  done

  echo '# as "$*"'
  for argument in "$*"; do
    echo "$argument"
  done

  echo '# as $*'
  for argument in $*; do
    echo "$argument"
  done
}
```

```sh
$ test_args "1 2" three four
# as "$@"
1 2
three
four
# as "$*"
1 2 three four
# as $*
1
2
three
four
```

Since you're exclusively using long options separated from their arguments by spaces,

```sh
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    ( --network )           NETWORK="$2"; shift ;;
    ( --network=?* )        NETWORK="${1#*=}" ;;
    ( --instance_name )     INSTANCE_NAME="$2"; shift ;;
    ( --instance_name=?* )  INSTANCE_NAME="${1#*=}" ;;
    ( -* )                  echo "Illegal option -- $1" >&2; exit 2 ;;
    ( * )                   break ;;  # perhaps non-options are used later
  esac
  shift
done
```

This loops on each option and parses it. There are two conditions for each option, which lets us handle when the arguments are spaced from the options (`--network bobnet`) or when they're assigned to the options (`--network=bobnet`). Spaced means we need to refer to the next argument (thus the extra `shift`) while assigned means we need to use [parameter subsitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSOREX2) to remove the characters at the front of the string up until (and including) the first `=`.

The final `shift` pulls the first item off of the argument list so we can operate on the next one. Shifting separately for the two-argument clauses (rather than ending with `shift 2`) also allows for binary options like `--verbose`, which doesn't contain an argument.

You can also use a `while getopts` loop to support a mix of short and long arguments; see my [more detailed post on getopts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466267/519360).

Comment: This is very useful, thank you!